# How to access outside world from Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I faced with the problem that I cannot send emails from K8s pod using `smtp.gmail.com` and `587` port. I tried to use `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet` but nothing has changed. With `dnsPolicy: Default` everything seems OK but I can't use this approach since pods should be able to resolve other pods from the cluster. Btw, `ConfigMap` with Google's dns didn't help too:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  upstreamNameservers: |
    [“8.8.8.8”, “8.8.4.4”]
```

Are there any ideas?
Thanks in advance. 
PS, my Kubernetes version is v1.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it just a syntax error in your configmap with quotes (" vs “)
If you run

`kubectl -n kube-system logs kube-dns-xxxx -c dnsmasq`

you will get a syntax error, instead of

`upstreamNameservers to [8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4]`

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach to solve this problem - you can write Google DNS (8.8.8.8) in container's resolve.conf during its startup.